# A Subspace of the Degree $3$ Polynomials Space for which $P(5)=0$

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

The problem is the following:

> Given the space of the polynomials $V=P(x)$ of degree $3$ prove the following:
>
> 1. The set $U$ which is defined as the set of the elements for which $P(5)=0$ is a subspace of $V$.
> 2. Find a basis for $U$.
> 3. If it was asked that $P(x)$ has $2$ also as a root then show that the new subset $W$, which is defined as $W=\{ p(x):p(x)=(x-5)(x-2)(b_0+b_2x)\}$ is also a subspace of $V$ and find a basis for it.

So, I do face difficulties in the first and the last one. I wrote down the elements of $V$:
\begin{equation}
V= \{ P(x)=a_1x^3+b_1x^2+c_1x+d_1, (a_1,b_1,c_1,d_1) \in \mathbb{R} \}
\end{equation}
Then I took the elements of $U$ to be of the form:
\begin{equation}
V= \{ p(x) \in \mathbb{R}:p(x)=(x-5)(a_2x^2+b_2x+c_2), (a_2,b_2,c_2) \in \mathbb{R} \}
\end{equation}
since $5$ is a root of $P(x)$. But I do not know how to proceed. I mean I know that I have to prove that $U$ has the properties of a subspace, but should I find the connection between the coefficients $a_i, b_i, c_i$? And how to use that relation?

Any ideas?

Thank you!

Comment: typo, 3. is missing something?

Comment: You can use your factorization to prove it is a subspace. Easier to prove the properties directly. Is the sum of two elements of $U$ in $U$? Let $p(x)$, $q(x)$ be in $U$. Then $p(5)=0$, $q(5)=0$, so $(p+q)(5)=0$. And so on. For dimension, it may be easier to show $x-5$, $(x-5)^2$, $(x-5)^3$ is a basis. Show they are linearly independent. That shows the dimension of $U$ is $\ge 3$. But it is not $4$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Ok I can see how I could prove the subspace properties. But the way you put it, how should I do it for the basis, now I got confused. .

Comment: Look at a linear combination $a(x-5)^3+b(x-5)^2+c(x-5)$. If this is identically $0$, then the degree $3$ term is $0$, so $a=0$. But then $b=9$, but then $c=0$. There are other ways.

Comment: @AndréNicolas I guess you take a linear combination of $(x-5)^n, n=1,2,3$ because is already factorized in that way, right? Sorry for asking perhaps trivial things, it is one of my first attempts in this kind of exercises with polynomials..

Comment: A  fancier (but one line) way to show $U$ is a subspace is given by Berci. About the choice of $(x-5)^n$, I think of it as fairly natural.  Your approach, which also works nicely, leads to basis $x-5$, $x(x-5)$, and $x^2(x-5)$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Well, I am definitely not familiar with these exercises in order to see those things so fast, I am mean I need my time and to write things down first. But still for the basis, at least how should I begin?

Comment: I wrote out a sketch, it is the fourth comment. The same method will work for $x^2(x-5)$, $x(x-5)$, $x-5$. First show they are linearly independent. Then observe that $U$ has dimension $\le 3$ because it is a proper subspace of $V$. We have found three linearly independent elements. So $U$ has dimension $3$, and our three polynomials give a basis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$1$. Let $\mathcal{P}_1(x)=\sum a_ix^i,\mathcal{P}_2(x)=\sum b_ix^i\in U$ then $[\mathcal{P}_1 + \mathcal{P}_2](5)=\sum (a_i+b_i)5^i=\sum a_i5^i+\sum b_i5^i=0+0=\mathcal{P}_1(5)+\mathcal{P}_2(5)$.

Can you prove the second property from here?

2.
By definition $a_0+5a_1+5^2a_2+5^3a_3=0\Rightarrow a_0=-5a_1-25a_2-125a_3$.

- Claim that the set $T$={$-5a_1-25a_2-125a_3,xa_1,x^2a_2,x^3a_3$} is a basis for $U$.

It's easy to show that the set is L.I. since it has only 3 free variables it's dimension is 3 ,now we have to show that $dim(U)=3$.Suppose that $dim(U)=4$ then it should contain every polynomial of degree at least 4,since $\mathcal{P}(x)=x-2\notin U$ it follows that $dim(U)<4$ and $spam(T)\subseteq U$
 it follows that $dim(U)=3$ hence $T$ is a basis.

Comment: I see... But what I did was another approach. I just showed that I can form any $p(x) \in U$ wiith as a linear combination of elements of the supposed basis $T$. Moreover, I showed that the elements of $T$ are linearly independent. Is that enough?

Comment: Yes,very well,by definition "a basis is a linearly independent spanning set" in your first affirmation you proved that $T$ spams $U$ and after that you proved that $T$ is L.I. it follows straightforward that $T$ is a basis.

Answer (score 1):

There is no relation between the coefficients you use: these $a_1,b_1,c_1,d_1$ and $a_2,b_2,c_2$ can be arbitrary.

**Hint:**
One way to prove that $U$ is a subspace is to find a linear map with kernel exactly $U$.

> $V\to\Bbb R,\ f\mapsto f(5)$

You can also use it for 3.

Comment: I am not really sure how to do that.. :/